# SQL2008 Max Memory set to 10GB, Target/Total perfmon counters report it's using 1.6GB. What's up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Running SQL2008 R2 32bit on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise with 12GB of RAM. Inside the Memory settings of the SQL instance I've got max memory set to 10000MB but it isn't going past 1.6GB according to the following query.

```
SELECT object_name,counter_name,instance_name, (cntr_value/1024) as Memory_in_MB, 
    cntr_type FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE counter_name IN ('Target Server Memory (KB)','Total Server Memory (KB)')
```

Am I running into an issue due to the 32 bit OS/SQL install? Or do I need to configure something additional to allow it access to more than the 3GB? Windows is detecting 12GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from you post; is Windows 32-Bit as well?

You will need to [**enable AWE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190673.aspx) in order to use the extra memory in a 32-bit environment.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. It is 32 bit. I did enable AWE but I'm still seeing 1.6GB as the target/total memory. EDIT: Just saw the bit about restarting the SQL service. I will try this after hours and report back.

Comment: Make sure you also grant Lock Pages in Memory to the SQL service account.  That gets missed sometimes.

Comment: That was it. Added the account to that policy and restarted SQL. Now using 8GB of RAM. Thanks :)